# Symbolic Math in a Computer Algebra System

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symbolic-computation

I am currently conducting my research on the spectrum of dephased of complex Hadamard matrices. Analytically, I was able to prove that two matrices A and B have equal non-zero trace and are equivalent to Tao’s isolated matrix $S_{6}$, then they share the same spectra. Now I would like to present the explicit calculation of the eigrnvalues for each possible trace. I tried doing this in MATLAB, and it gave me float-point numbers. I tried to use symbolic math, but I’m still unable to get the result the wanted.

An example is the following:
Suppose I wanted to calculate for the eigenvalues of the matrix $$M:\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
We can easily get that the eigenvalues are {a,0}.

The matrix $S_{6}$ consists of 1s and $\omega$s, where $\omega=e^{2 \pi i/6}$. Now I want to calculate for the eigenvalues of $S_{6}$, and I want it to be expressed in terms of $\omega$(for some) for an accurate result. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: Why are the eigenvalues even in the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $\omega$?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  If you're looking for a computer algebra system (CAS) there are a few out there to choose from.  They all take a bit of work to get what you want.  FWIW, Maxima (formerly DoE-Macsyma) is freely available and works under both Windows and Linux.

Comment: I wanted to calculate for the eigenvalues with 100% accuracy, e.g. expressions in terms of $\omega$. I’m unfamiliar as to how it was done in a different paper, which only stated that they used a computer algebra system.

Comment: Sorry I have a hard time explaining it, but here is a similar paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1176, check page 18.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
function [M,V,D] = S6
  w = exp(2i*sym(pi)/3);
  M = [
    1 1 1 1 1 1;
    1 1 w w w^2 w^2;
    1 w 1 w^2 w^2 w;
    1 w w^2 1 w w^2;
    1 w^2 w^2 w 1 w;
    1 w^2 w w^2 w 1
    ];
  [V,D] = eig(M);
end
```

Comment: Thanks man! The first line of code of yours was the missing piece.

Comment: Glad to help.  You may find the documentation of `subexpr` helpful, if you aren't already familiar with it.